# Decomposition on irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, characters

Please check my solution of the following problem: Let $V_\lambda$ be an irreducible representation of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ with the highest weight $\lambda$. Decompose into a direct sum of irreducible representations $\mbox{Sym}^2(V_5)$.

Since $\lambda = 5$ is the highest weight, the character is given by $\chi_{V_5} = q^5 + q^3 + q^1 + q^{-1} + q^{-3} + q^{-5}$.
$$(q^5 + q^3 + q^1 + q^{-1} + q^{-3} + q^{-5})^2 = q^{10} + 2q^8 + 3q^6 + 4q^4 + 5q^2 + 6 + 5q^{-2} + 4q^{-4} + 3q^{-6} + 2q^{-8} + q^{-10}$$

So the decomposition is $\mbox{Sym}^2(V_5) = V_{10} \oplus V_8 \oplus V_6 \oplus V_4 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_0$ and the dimensions of irreducible components are $\mbox{dim} V_{10} = 1$, $\mbox{dim} V_8 = 2$, $\mbox{dim} V_6 = 3$, $\mbox{dim} V_4 = 4$, $\mbox{dim} V_2 = 5$, $\mbox{dim} V_0 = 6$.

Is it right? It seems to me that I have done the task for $V_5 \otimes V_5$ but not for $\mbox{Sym}^2 V_5$.If so, please explain to me what to do with the symmetric power.

Comment: Right, you have decomposed the tensor square, which gives you both the symmetric and the alternating part. Now you need to pick out the symmetric part. BTW, it is a poor idea to use the same notation for a simple module with some highest weight and for the weight spaces of that module.

Comment: Your notation change now makes your decomposition not actually the decomposition into irreducibles.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have corrected the notation. But it is still unclear to me how to distinguish the symmetric part from it. It seems that I already use that $q^k q^l = q^{k+l} = q^l q^k$ when opened the brackets and collected the same summands.

Comment: Yes, the characters live in a commutative ring. What you need to use is that you know the dimension of the symmetric powers, the dimensions of the irreducibles and then to note that the highest weight vector (i.e. the one of weight $10$) of the tensor square is a symmetric element.

Comment: Since $\mbox{dim} V_5 = 5 + 1 =6$ the dimension of symmetric power is $\mbox{dim} (\mbox{Sym}^2 V_5) = C_7^2 = 21$. Does it imply that all irreducibles are from symmetric part (because sum of their dimensions is  $21$ too)?

Comment: No, the total sum of dimensions of those irreducibles is more than $21$.

Comment: Is it possible to choose a decomposition as $\mbox{Sym}^2 V_5 = V_{10} \oplus V_4$ with the multiplicity of $V_4$ equals to $2$ because of $(10+1) + 2 \cdot (4+1) = 21$?

Comment: How could you get multiplicities when there are no such in the tensor square?

Comment: A further hint: Similarly to the highest weight, what happens for the other weights of $V_5$ when you "square" them?

Comment: Other weights sum up with each other because they are the eigenvalues.